# How to display AMP tags from non AMP tags in the body section created with CKEDITOR dynamically

Tags: amp-html

I have a simple CMS build in PHP, MYSQLI and HTML elements where there is a page(post.php) to display all contents dynamically. I uses CKEDITOR html editor to write body section of post/article.

I am excited to implement AMP version of each post/article although I know some disadvantages of it. I have change my code in post.php and many tags are working in AMP except the tags inside body section created using CKEDITOR.

I am displaying each post in my post.php as

```html
<!-- Main Content -->
        <div class="main-content single">
            <h1 class="post-title"><?php echo $post['title']; ?></h1>
            <div class="post-content">
                <?php echo html_entity_decode($post['body']); ?>

            </div>           
        </div>
        <!--// Main Content -->
```

The main difficulty is to display the tags(e.g img, videos) of body section into amp tags. Please can anyone provide me the solution or useful links from where i can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$ampify_img_1 = str_ireplace('<img', "<amp-img", $post['body']);
$ampify_img_2 = preg_replace('/<amp-img(.*?)/?>/', '<amp-img$1 width="600" height="400" layout="responsive">', $ampify_img_1);
```

600 and 400 is for img aspect ratio, can also use 6 and 4

result post

```html
<p><?=$ampify_img_2;?></p>
```